# jquery-ui-1.8.14 Autocomplete with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm not very much into js and programing in general, but I'm very stuck on something that really shouldn't be too difficult. Feel free to visit the test page:

[REMOVED LINK]

I have three autocomplete fields: Current club, nation and career stats.
Autocomplete works perfectly for the career stats where I can also add fields and the autocomplete also works for the added field.

But for the current club and nation fields, I get results while typing but when I click the correct output it doesn't show up in the input-field.

I can make it work using other js-libraries, but then it no longer work for the add-button career stats fields.

I use the following libraries:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jq-ac-script.js"></script>
```

The current club html looks like:

```
<p>
    Current club <label>:</label>
    <input type="text" id="currentclub" />
</p>
```

In the custom made jq-ac-script.js (I originally found this somewhere online - don't remember where) the important part is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#currentclub" ).autocomplete({
        source: "get_club_list.php",
        minLength: 1    
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
       return $( "<li></li>" )
       .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
       .append( item.currentclub )
       .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

The "get_club_list.php" looks like:

```
<?php
include ("dbsetup.php");

$return_arr = array();
$param = $_GET["term"];

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM FootNews_CLUB 
    WHERE clubShortName LIKE '%$param%'");

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['currentclub']           = $row['clubShortName'];
    array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysql_close($conn);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Any ideas whereas to why the selected club doesn't show up when I click it would be appriciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, used my php code. Cool, glad I could help.
http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

Not sure why you are using the autocomplete code with `_renderItem` in it. I don't think you need it.

Change the php code to this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['currentclub']  = $row['clubShortName'];
    $row_array['value']   = $row['clubShortName'];
    array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
}
```

And, the jquery to:

```
$( "#currentclub" ).autocomplete({
    source: "get_club_list.php",
    minLength: 1    
});
```

You can read through my tutorial again but the autocomplete needs a `label` or `value` field returned. It then populates the select list and the corresponding input field with that value.

I left in `$row_array['currentclub']  = $row['clubShortName'];` because I don't know if you are grabbing that later on. If you are not, you don't need that line either.

Since you control the returned data and can specify a `label` and/or `value` field in the php, I don't understand why you are using the `_renderItem` for any of the autocompletes.

BTW, you should add `mysql_real_escape_string` to your php code for some sql injection protection: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That fixed it, and thanks also for the link back to your tutorial.